# When updating a url/html title dynamically, how can I get a facebook like button to register the change? (NOT the href in fb:like)

Tags: javascript, facebook, html, facebook-like

I have a webapp that changes the url using window.history.pushState() based on the content that is dynamically loaded. I also have a facebook like button on the page that corresponds to the current element/url (also changed dynamically), and I also change the title of the page (document.title).

When I click the button when it's running, the update on facebook says "User likes this link". The link is the correct link going to the right URL, but beneath it is a little message that says

```
Original Title
Original URL
```

How can I get the facebook update to instead read:

```
Updated Title
Updated URL
```

Best,
Sami

EDIT:

Alternatively, does anybody know how to change the message that the facebook like button posts? If I could create my own message, I could easily fix this.

Comment: This thread could use some love.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like this question has been answered before here [Update FB:Like URL Dynamically using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764129/update-fblike-url-dynamically-using-javascript) 
there are a number of different solutions given

**Edit to answer the clarified question:**
The problem is recounted here [Facebook Share doesn't pick up title / description meta tags that are changed after page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656803/facebook-share-doesnt-pick-up-title-description-meta-tags-that-are-changed-af)

To summarize: Facebook scrapes and caches your page title and description, the information is not submitted by the client.

One way around this is to have your server parse the hash or query string, as your javascript would, and serve a page with the title you want.

Comment: Again - in my question I clearly state that the url updates just fine - it's the message that is the issue.